# Unable to attach a new NetDecoder to a NetModel following the documentation

Tags: neural-networks

I am following the documentation in the page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetModel.html.

I am getting error when I try to execute the code given for attaching NetDecoder for a given model.

```
NetModel["LeNet", "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"cat", "dog"}}]]
```

Output

`NetReplacePart::invspdec: NetDecoder[{"Class", \[Ellipsis]}] taking a length-2 vector of real numbers, cannot be attached to port Output, which produces a length-10 vector of real numbers.`

Can someone explain me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I can find to replace the output decoder is by copying over the net up to the last `Ramp` layer and then adding the rest back in manually:

```
net = NetModel["LeNet"];
net = NetFlatten @ NetChain[
   { NetTake[net, 9], (* the Ramp layer has index 9 *)
     LinearLayer[], SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"cat", "dog"}}]
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I'd normally do it as well. I wish `NetReplace` had a nice use-case here as well but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Thank you @Sjoerd Smit

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, this example given by the documentation won't evaluate and (as far as I'm aware) never could have evaluated. You didn't do anything wrong here; it's a documentation bug. The following explains *why* it doesn't evaluate.

LeNet's `"Output"` port (before decoding) is a vector of reals of length 10 - in the case of LeNet, it outputs something approximating the probabilities that the input was a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9.

LeNet has a `NetDecoder` by default, which we can look at with `NetExtract[NetModel["LeNet"], "Output"]`.

[image]

This is also a `"Class"` `NetDecoder`, but unlike yours it has **10 labels**. This means that the output from the network (remember, a length-10 vector of probabilities per class) can be mapped to this list of labels.

The `NetDecoder` that you've defined only has **two** labels ("cat" and "dog"), and so the decoder doesn't match up with the network output.

Comment: In all fairness to the OP, though, the line `NetModel["LeNet", "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"cat", "dog"}}]]` is verbatim from the documentation of `NetModel` (3rd line in the Scope section).

Comment: Totally agree, it's a bug in the documentation to have given an example that won't evaluate.

Comment: @CarlLange, could you please tell how to change the number of labels in network?
That would be helpful

Comment: @KrSudharsan Sorry, I missed this; Sjoerd's answer is exactly what I would have added.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for spotting the documentation error and the limitation of NetReplacePart.

Good news for the future: NetReplacePart will be improved in the next version.

In 12.1, it will be possible to write:

```
NetReplacePart[NetModel["LeNet"],
   {10 -> LinearLayer[], "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"cat", "dog"}}]}
]
```

(replacing the layer(s) that need to be "reshaped", additionally to the output)

[image]